# WCF Service setup does not uninstall previous version

Tags: c#, .net, dll, installation

I have a setup project which gives me a .msi file

Installation attempts fail on this machine, which already had an earlier version installed. A MessageBox reports an error and asks me to remove it from Add/Remove programs.

I have set `RemovePreviousVersions = true`

Using an updated version it now installs without error, however the referenced dll has not updated to the new version.

What should i do, so that the installer either repairs or uninstalls and reinstalls it automatically?

Please help.